# I am getting an Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'reactstrap'

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react navbar. Getting this error.
 Module not found:

```
Can't resolve 'reactstrap' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Node\MERNShoppingList\client\src\components'

./src/components/AppNavbar.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'reactstrap' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Node\MERNShoppingList\client\src\components'
```

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

**AppNavbar.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        Collapse,
        Navbar,
        NavbarToggler,
        NavbarBrand,
        Nav,
        NavItem,
        NavLink,
        Container
    } from 'reactstrap';
```

**APP.JS**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import AppNavbar from './components/AppNavbar';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import './App.css';

    class App extends Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <div className="App">
                    <AppNavbar/>
                </div>
            );
       }
     }

    export default App;
```

Please Help.

Comment: Have you installed `reactstrap` & `bootstrap`?

Comment: Yes I have installed both

Comment: Post the component where you are using `reactstrap`.

Comment: See the question ,  I have added

Comment: Such error usually occurs when your app is already running and you install new package using `npm install`, after that you need to restart your app. Try to restart your app. If still not solved try to post complete code for your component.

Comment: Why they are marking negative? They can't answer still marking negative.

Comment: I have restarted the app, still getting the error. Have added App.js and Appnavbar.js, Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install reactstrap.

```
npm i -S reactstrap
```

Comment: There is no difference between npm install [Package Name] and npm install [Package Name] –save in the later version after npm 5.0.0 onwards, right?

Answer (score 8):

Try using `npm install --save reactstrap`

While installing any npm package,it is recommended to use `--save` along with `npm install`.

It adds the package into your package.json.

***For Installation***: `npm install --save reactstrap`

***For Uninstallation***:`npm uninstall --save reactstrap`
This will remove the package from package.json

Answer (score 2):

One way is to Run `npm i reactstrap --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the package and reinstall by `npm uninstall reactstrap` and 
install it agin by `npm i -s reactstrap bootstrap`
tell me if it work or not

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error.

the reason was a typing mistake,

; mistakenly put before the ' in import

check those kinds of mistakes as well.

import { Media } from 'reactstrap;' <-- error